# Bootstrap-switch documentation?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

```
$.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.size = 'large';
```

This function i see on bootstrap switch size but does not work.
please help.
The link of the size as follows
[bootstrap switch documentation](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/options.html)
[picture of bootstrap switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baXia.png)
[image]

i want small size bootstrap switch

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g68jxxmz/1/?

Comment: Like Arun said, but change the value like http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/g68jxxmz/2/

Comment: yes this was right sir